# Creating boxplot in same graph and scale with two different length of dataset

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I have a two set of data with different length.
Sameple datatype is:

```
A=c(423,430,500,460,457,300,325,498,450,453,486,459)
B=c(300,325,356345,378,391,367)
```

I want to create boxplot for them within a same graph and same scale. I tried it in ggplot2 in R. I also tried default `boxplot` in R.

```
boxplot (A~B)
```

but it showed error. I would like to use ggplot2 in R.

Comment: for base R you would use `boxplot (A, B)`. You would use the formula notation if the variable on the rhs is categorical ie `boxplot (A ~ I(A>440))`. Probably worth thinking of a technique to deal with the extreme outlier.

Answer (score 2):

You have to create a dataset with those 2 vectors and then plot.

```
library(ggplot2)

A=c(423,430,500,460,457,300,325,498,450,453,486,459)
B=c(300,325,356345,378,391,367)

# create a dataset for each vector
df_A = data.frame(value=A, id="A")
df_B = data.frame(value=B, id="B")

# combine datasets
df = rbind(df_A, df_B)

# create the box plot
ggplot(df, aes(id, value)) + geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much